# This is dummy text but I can't get each review div to display in rows. There is 3 of them 'review1' 'review2' 'review3'

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML. Should I put display: grid in review or the children.

````
    <div class="review1">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vitae velit at. Quam animi qui sed delectus harum dignissimos distinctio. Ducimus, assumenda explicabo vero earum deserunt quisquam ut quo officiis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="review2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vitae velit at. Quam animi qui sed delectus harum dignissimos distinctio. Ducimus, assumenda explicabo vero earum deserunt quisquam ut quo officiis.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="review3">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vitae velit at. Quam animi qui sed delectus harum dignissimos distinctio. Ducimus, assumenda explicabo vero earum deserunt quisquam ut quo officiis.</p>
    </div>```
````

Comment: `display: flex` on your parent `div`

Comment: It's putting it in columns

Comment: Add `flex-direction: row` as well in that case

Comment: It's not working. it's putting it in a column, all on top of each other.

Comment: You must have contradicting code somewhere, have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/byn92rqo/

Comment: `flex-direction: row` is enabled by default in flexbox @MattHammer5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose between `grid` and `flex`. Just wrap your content with div:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="review1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vitae velit at. Quam animi qui sed delectus harum dignissimos distinctio. Ducimus, assumenda explicabo vero earum deserunt quisquam ut quo officiis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="review2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vitae velit at. Quam animi qui sed delectus harum dignissimos distinctio. Ducimus, assumenda explicabo vero earum deserunt quisquam ut quo officiis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="review3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vitae velit at. Quam animi qui sed delectus harum dignissimos distinctio. Ducimus, assumenda explicabo vero earum deserunt quisquam ut quo officiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="review1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vitae velit at. Quam animi qui sed delectus harum dignissimos distinctio. Ducimus, assumenda explicabo vero earum deserunt quisquam ut quo officiis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="review2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vitae velit at. Quam animi qui sed delectus harum dignissimos distinctio. Ducimus, assumenda explicabo vero earum deserunt quisquam ut quo officiis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="review3">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus vitae velit at. Quam animi qui sed delectus harum dignissimos distinctio. Ducimus, assumenda explicabo vero earum deserunt quisquam ut quo officiis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked thx, Another question, how do I display my review in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Look in updated answer, just put `margin: 0 auto;`  and some `width` on your container